# Understanding better the parallelism between linear algebra and ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Linear algebra methods in ODE is a classical course at the university but to me it seems that the main point of such courses is to highlight the similarities between solving linear system and ODE systems. I'm interested in understanding how the linear algebra works when I consider my ODE as a linear self operator on the vector space of real valued functions.

Let me be more precise. Let $$ y'+p(x)y=0 \ \ (\ast)$$ be our linear homogenous ODE. Let $$ L[x](-) : (-)'+p(x)(-) $$ be the linear operator associated with $(\ast)$, which means we are interested in the kernel of $L[x]$. By the Uniqueness and Existence Theorem (UET) we know we have a $1$-dimensional family of solutions to $(\ast)$, and this agrees with the reasoning that if we have $1$ constrain (the ODE) in a $2$ dimensional vector space then the space of solutions should be $1$-dimensional (I'm avoiding degenerate cases here).

The problem is that the vector space $L[x]$ is defined on is **infinite** dimensional. so we cannot really do the same reasoning. Maybe this is an index issue (is $L[x]$ a Fredholm operator?)

> what is the precise linear algebra setting that allows me to conclude that the kernel of $L[x]$ is $1$-dimensional?

We can try to push our reasoning a little further and consider degree $2$ ODE fo the form $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 \ \ \ (\ast \ast)$$

In this case UET suggests we have a $2$-dimensional family of solutions which are pinned down by initial value of the function AND its derivative (so not a boundary value problem). The way I see this result is that somehow our vector representing a solution $y$ of $(\ast \ast)$ is somehow made by two components $$(y,y')$$

> even in the case, I'd like to understand the correct linear algebra setting which shows why the kernel of the operator representing $(\ast \ast)$ is $2$-dimensional

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Do you know [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Comment: no, do you think the answer lies there?

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at the so-called behavioral approach to dynamical systems. It deals exactly with what you are asking. The main resource is that book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2953-5.